# How to sort a listbox full of files with (3 category) dash delimited names via radio buttons in VB.Net 2017?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, filenames, delimiter, alphabetical-sort

So I am building my first program in quite some time and have bashed my way through most of it successfully. Now I am running into a problem and need to ask some advice.

Description: I have a directory of notepad text (of lyrics and chord arrangements) files with titles formatted as follows.
Songtitle-Artist-Key.txt
First I browse for their directory which populates a listbox. Then after I select a song from said listbox, it populates 1 of 3 textboxes depending upon which textbox I assign it to via command buttons (some songs have up to 3 pages.) All of this works fine so far. (Future quest would be to automatically put a song with 2 or 3 pages into each respective textbox when the first one is clicked.)

Goal: I have 3 radio buttons labeled Title, Artist, and Key within a group control. These are meant to be used to sort the listbox by their respective names, Title, Artist, and Key.

Questions: Can I sort this listbox according to delimited category, or do I need to have 3 separate listboxes (and how would I keep them synchronized), or do I need to have some sort of data element involved? Any suggestions, thoughts, examples, or ideas welcome!

Edit: This says exactly what I want it to say, having read the how to ask page and having searched for over a full day, I am reopening this question.

Thanks,
DiggDuggster

Comment: You should now bash your way thru [ask] and then the [tour] to learn how to use the site effectively.

Comment: Use a List(Of Class) as the ListBox `DataSource`. The Class needs to contain all the relevant elements you derive from the source files (Title, Artist, Key, Song Text, Chords etc.). Add some properties that are used to format the ListBox visible list and assign those properties to the ListBox `DisplayMember`, based on a RadioButton selection. A ListView or TreeView may give you some more options on the data presentation.

Comment: Considering that it was already 5am when I posted this and after having searched most of yesterday, I would surmise that I searched pretty well. I will look at the "how to ask" article however. I had no idea there even was one! Thanks for the heads up. Jimi, thanks, I will look further into what you said!

Comment: So I read the how to ask page, and extensively searched for a solution for a days, I have found nothing, even on other sites, so I came to the best community I knew, to ask. I clearly stated my situation as best as I can explain it and stated my question exactly the way I think it needed to be asked. I have been using this site as a guest for about 10 years. Instead of being dinged, perhaps a formal explanation on why this wasn't a good question is in order? Others were able to figure out what I was asking with no problem. I request this be reopened for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with an older version of vb you will not be able to use interpolated strings ($). Change to String.Format. Other explanation is in code comments.

```
Public Class frmSortedList
    Private lstSongs As New List(Of Song)
    Public SortOrder As Integer = 0
    Private Sub frmSortedList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim lstFileName As New List(Of String)
        lstFileName.Add("Star Spangled Banner-Francis Scott Keyes-G.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("Jailhouse Rock-Elvis Presley-F.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("Macho Insecurity-Dead Kennedys-G.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("(We Are) The Road Crew-Motorhead-F.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("Moonlight Drive-The Doors-B.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("While My Guitar Gently Weeps-The Beatles-B.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("Waffle-Sevendust-G.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("Don't Take Your Guns To Town-Johnny Cash-G.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("Where Eagles Dare-Iron Maiden-B.txt")
        lstFileName.Add("London Calling-The Clash-F.txt")
        'your list will come from your Directory
        'loop through you list of file names (or an array of file names
        'call the constructor of Song passing the file name
        'add the Song object to the list
        For Each file As String In lstFileName
            Dim s As New Song(file)
            lstSongs.Add(s)
        Next
        'The ListBox will call .ToString on the objects you add
        'to determine what to display
        ListBox1.DataSource = lstSongs
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FileName"
        'To access any of the properties of the items in the ListBox
        'Cast the object stored in the ListBox back to song
        Dim item As Song = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, Song)
        Debug.Print($"Title: {item.Title}, Artist: {item.Artist}, Key: {item.MusicKey}")
        'You can set the value property to any property of Song
        Dim thefile As String = CStr(ListBox1.SelectedValue)
        Debug.Print(thefile)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnArtist_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnArtist.Click
        'A little link code to sort the list
        SortOrder = 1
        Dim lstArtists As List(Of Song) = lstSongs.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Artist).ToList
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.DataSource = lstArtists
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FileName"
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTitle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTitle.Click
        SortOrder = 0
        Dim lstTitle As List(Of Song) = lstSongs.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Title).ToList
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.DataSource = lstTitle
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FileName"
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnKey_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnKey.Click
        SortOrder = 2
        Dim lstKey As List(Of Song) = lstSongs.OrderBy(Function(s) s.MusicKey).ToList
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.DataSource = lstKey
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FileName"
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Song
    Public ReadOnly Property Title As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Artist As String
    Public ReadOnly Property MusicKey As String
    Public ReadOnly Property ShortFileName As String
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Sub New(file As String)
        FileName = file 'the full file name that was passed to the constructor
        Dim index As Integer = file.IndexOf(".") 'Find where the extension starts
        ShortFileName = file.Remove(index) 'Get rid of .txt
        Dim parts As String() = ShortFileName.Split("-"c) 'Split returns and array
        Title = parts(0)
        Artist = parts(1)
        MusicKey = parts(2)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        'The ListBox calls .ToString on the objects you added
        'You can return any property of combination of properties
        'you want to display
        'if you don't override you will get the fully qualified name of the object Argh!
        Select Case frmSortedList.SortOrder
            Case 0
                Return ShortFileName
            Case 1 'Artist
                Return $"{Artist} - {Title} -  {MusicKey}"
            Case 2 'key
                Return $"{MusicKey} - {Title} - {Artist}"
            Case Else
                Return ShortFileName
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I am working with Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Let me get this going and edit whatever needs to be changed as far as control names go. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay Mary, I have plugged in this code, renamed the controls in the code as appropriate, and attempted to eliminate the errors. I have 1 error that remains and it is this:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Message  '.ctor' is not a valid identifier.   0 

When I search for this string it tells me the string does not exist. I will double check my file names right now to verify its not a file naming convention error, and get back to you on this. Thanks again.

Comment: here is an example of my file naming convention: ...    Change It-Stevie Ray Vaughan-G#m.txt

Comment: Now after correcting the issue as best I could figure out, I can open the directory, and the list populates correctly and I can place the lyrics/chord sheet in any of the panes, however, when I use a radio button to sort it, it empties the listbox and the program locks up and I cannot load the listbox again. It gives me this error...

System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

Comment: Additionally, my forms name is Textera_Form and the projects name is Textera1a

Comment: Have you set the datasource to nothing before re-assigning to the sorted list?

Comment: I just tried this with radio buttons instead of buttons and it works for me. I used the radio button CheckedChanged event and added an `If rbKey.Checked Then` and then pasted the code from the button inside the if.